# Entry Type field

Tags: custom-fields, fields, entry-type

Has anyone used this add-on: [**Entry Type field**](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/entry-type)

I have it working in the publish page but when I try to use conditionals on the front it fails to work. The developer outlines use as:

```
{if your_entry_type_field == 'link'}
  {link_url}
{if:else your_entry_type_field == 'video'}
  {video}
{if:elseif your_entry_type_field == 'image'}
  {image}
{/if}
```

This doesn't seem to work.

This is the setup for the field:

[image: field]

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="prosjektstotte" category="3" limit="" status="open" orderby="date" sort="desc" disable="category_fields|member_data|trackbacks" dynamic="yes"}  
  {if open_fields == "programomrader"}
  <div class="article-block">
    <div class="w-clearfix article-block-inner">
      <h1 class="article-block-title">{if user_language == "no"}{title}{if:else}{if title_en_programomrader}{title_en_programomrader}{/if}</h1>
      <div class="paragraph article-paragraph-block">
      {if user_language == "no"}<h6>{summary_no_programomrader}</h6>{if:else}<h6>{summary_en_programomrader}</h6>{/if}
      {if user_language == "no"}{text_no_programomrader}{if:else}{text_en_programomrader}{/if}
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
   {/if}
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

What I thought it did was show only the content inside the fields made visible by selecting "programomrader". Instead it is just showing the last entry posted in the "prosjektstotte" channel.

Putting just `{open_fields}` in the template returns "programomrader".

Paul

Comment: I have it working on a couple of sites with conditionals. Show us your template code and also what it displays on the front-end so we can better assist.

Comment: Hi Stephen, thanks. Please see the added info in my edit above.

Comment: If you remove the conditional and just add `{open_fields}` what do you see on the page?

Comment: If I add {open_fields} it outputs: programomrader (the name of the selected field)

Comment: So, isn't the conditional correct? `{open_fields}` does not equal `prosjektstotte` (it equals `programomrader`) so it shows nothing.

Comment: Perhaps Im using it incorrectly. I thought I could filter which field types I had on a page. Like: {if open_fields == "prosjektstotte"}Project{/if} if open_fields == "test"}Test{/if} etc

Comment: Yes, that's correct. In your example, you only show `{open_fields == "prosjektstotte"} ... {/if}`. What do you have between `{open_fields == "programomrader"} ... {/if}`?

Comment: Sorry this is what I meant: {open_fields == "programomrader"} ... {/if}. It shows nothing

Comment: What happens when you do this: {if "{open_fields}" == "programomrader"}

Comment: Also, can you test by manually putting the `entry_id` of an entry you know has "programomrader" selected in the `channel:entries` tag? `entry_id="..."`